# Changing UI Panel conditionally

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Tried to find an answer to this for over a week now. I have tried multiple different ways and i must be doing something wrong. Here is the scenario. I have my game set up. Its a 2d unity game similar to Merge Planes. I have code that does all the player management like xp, gold and levelling up (its called LevelManager). I also have a UI Panel set up that loads up on button click from the main game screen. Its like the inventory so to speak. What i am trying to do is this. When the button is clicked i would like the panel to load a different sprite dependant on the player level. Imagine that if a player is level 1, the bg sprite on the panel should show an image with all but the first item blacked out. Then if the player is level 2, the second one is unlocked and now visible. I have tried everything for example 1) sprite arrays 2) using statics 3) instantiating the panel 4)using an onclick even listener on the button. If anyone is able to assist me in achieving this i would be super grateful. Please help me break it down so i understand what is going on. Ill need to know what line of code is best, what objects i am applying code to and all of that good stuff. Lets go back to basics please. Thank you in advance.
Neil

Answer (score 0):

It's hard helping you without seeing the code but I suggest you to do the following:
Assuming that you have a different background image for each level, sort them in a list or an array and load them according to the player's level. It will be something like this:

`private void Start{
    //backgrounds = your backgrounds array / list
    Instantiate(backgrounds[player.level-1], transform.position, transform.rotation);
}`

But again it's hard to know without seeing your code.

Comment: hi Bishok. Thank you very much for your reply. I will post the LevelManager script here so you can take a look. I will give your suggestion a go.

Comment: public static int currentLevel;
public int currentGold;
public int currentExperience;
public Text XPText;
public Text goldText;
public Text levelText;
private float neededExperience;

Comment: void Start()
{
 currentLevel = 1; currentExperience = 0; currentGold = 0;
XPText.text = "";
goldText.text = "";
levelText.text = "";
levelText.text = "";
    }

Comment: void Update()
{
Exp();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("car"))
                    UpdateGold();
            UpdateXP();
        }
    }

    void UpdateGold()
    {
        goldText.text = "Gold: " + currentGold;
        currentGold++;

    }

    void UpdateXP()
    {
        XPText.text = "XP: " + currentExperience;
        currentExperience++;
    }


    void LevelUp()
    {
        levelText.text = "Level: " + currentLevel;
        currentLevel += 1;

Comment: void Exp()
    {
        if (currentExperience >= neededExperience)
            LevelUp();
    }

Comment: sorry i dont know how to paste the code properly. I use a switch statement for the neededExperience variable. Also am i putting that code on the button, the panel or the empty Game Object that is holding my levelManager script?

Comment: i added the following 2 lines to the levelManager script. public Sprite[] panelSprites = new Sprite[10]; and also in the Start method Instantiate(panelSpries[currentLevel - 1], transform.position, transform.rotation); but nothing happens now. No image appears when the button is pressed. Being its object oriented programming, am i supposed to attach the code to the button, the panel or just having it running with work fine. Cos there is no reference to teh button yet in my script. I thank you again for your help.